# How to update a particular field of a particular object in Generic list in c#.net using LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

I am creating a Generic List of objects of Employee class.

```
List<Employee> EmployeeList = new List<Employee>
{
new Employee { ecode=1, ename="Rohit", salary=20000, mgrid="3" },
new Employee { ecode=2, ename="Sangeeta", salary=12000, mgrid="5"},
new Employee { ecode=3, ename="Sanjay", salary=10000, mgrid="5"},
new Employee { ecode=4, ename="Arun", salary=25000, mgrid="3"},
new Employee { ecode=5, ename="Zaheer", salary=30000, mgrid=null}  
};
```

*'mgrid'* is the Employee ID of the Manager. I want just increment the salary of the Managers.
I tried doing it using the following approach, but salaries of all the employees are getting incremented.

```
var mgrsal =  from e1 in emplst
              join e2 in emplst
              on e1.ecode.ToString() equals e2.mgrid into empdata
              select new Employee
              {
                  ecode = e1.ecode,
                  ename=e1.ename,
                  salary=e1.salary*1.1,
                  mgrid = e1.mgrid
              };
```

I am coding in C#.net in Visual Studio IDE and I also tried to use Contains() and Any() methods, but I am unable to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ is all about querying, not updating. You can use LINQ to get all managers from the list,

```
var managers = from e in emplst
               where emplst.Any(x => x.mgrid == e.ecode.ToString())
               select e;
```

or using `JOIN` (it would require implementing `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods on `Employee` class to make `Distinct` work:

```
var managers = (from e in emplst
               join e2 in emplst on e.ecode.ToString() equals e2.mgrid
               select e).Distinct();
```

and then iterate over and change the salary:

```
foreach(var manager in managers)
    manager.salary *= 1.1;
```

Comment: The final result requires all the employees to be displayed with only managers' salary incremented. Hence I have performed Union as follows     
    
var mgrsal = from m in emplst.Union(managers)
                         select m;                                      Is there any other better than this?

Comment: you still have all the employees in your initial list, so just write it out and you're done.

Comment: I tried it. Only the managers and their incremented salaries are displayed. hence I performed the Union.